# Separate super and sub class namespaces? If so, can a using namespace statement for a sub class allow a parent class func to be called directly?

Tags: c++, inheritance, namespaces, parent-child

My full question was a bit too long to describe in the title. I had some questions about namespaces, headers, and parent/child classes.

Would it would/be acceptable to do the following?

In ParentClass.h:

```
namespace prnt {

    class Parent {
        // Parent class
    };
}
```

In ChildClass.h:

```
namespace chld {

    class Child : public prnt::Parent {
        // Child Class
    };
}
```

As well as this, assuming that this is acceptable, in a program utilizing the above classes, would a using namespace statement for just the child class allow access to the Parent class's functions without specifying the namespace. For example:

If we did:

```
using namespace chld;
```

And then, somewhere in the program, we wanted to call on a function from the parent class, would we (could we) do it this way:

```
parentClassObject.parentFunction();
```

Or this way:

```
prnt::parentClassObject.parentFunction();
```

Thanks

Comment: Where is `parentClassObject` defined? Within the `prnt` namespace, or elsewhere? Accessing class members doesn't depend on the namespace (accessing the class object does).

Comment: Sorry, I guess I didn’t make it clear. parentClassObject would be defined in a program using the header files. I was just confused about whether or not the namespaces would effect what class member functions could be accessed in a program using the headers. In other words, would using the sub class namespace give us access to everything in the parent class namespace?

Comment: Namespaces never effect which class member functions you can access. They belong to the class, and it is the class that controls what members you can access. It doesn't matter of `parentClassObject` is in the global namespace, the `prnt` namespace, or the `wonderland` namespace. The child class accesses the base (parent) class's members the same way any derived class accesses base class members.

Comment: Thanks! I'm new to all this so I wasn't sure